# django south migration and USE_TZ=True

Tags: django, timezone, django-south

I've changed all my code to use `aware-time` by using `django.utils.timezone.now()`
I changed datetimefield to use `default=timezone.now`, and set `USE_TZ=True` in settings.py

After the changes, I ran south schemamigration command and it doesn't pick up the database fields change.

I'm using the south 0.7.6 and postgresql if that matters.

Here's the detailed change I made to make my entire site timezone aware.
[how do I make my site timezone aware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653369/how-do-i-make-my-site-timezone-aware)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994101/django-1-4-use-tz-migration-database-part-best-practices

Comment: It is not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use south, and change `USE_TZ=False` to `USE_TZ=True`, all your old migrations will likely break, and you'll get errors like:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (XXX)
while time zone support is active
```

I have not found a way to have south track changes in settings.py.  What I've done is alter the actual migration files.  These each have a number and are in the migrations subdirectory.

For each one that fails, add `from django.utils import timezone`, and modify any DateTimeField fields the same way as you did in your main code (making them time zone aware, or eliminating a specific non-timezone default date).

Alternately you can try to [reset your south migration history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625712/whats-the-recommended-approach-to-resetting-migration-history-using-django-sout).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Bryce's answer, these are the bash scripts we used to convert our south migrations to timezone-aware:

```
$ cd mysite/mainapp/migrations
$ find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/datetime.datetime.now/timezone.now/g' {} \;
$ find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e '/import datetime/{G;s/$/from django.utils import timezone/;}' {} \;
```

Used on OS X 10.11.5 "El Capitan."